# Using Worklight Studio Plugin with Rational Application Developer

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-rad

Is it possible to use the Worklight Studio plugin for eclipse with IBM's Rational Application Developer IDE (8.5).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the Worklight Studio version you are trying to use.

If you try to install the latest available version from Eclipse marketplace (the developer edition which is 6.1.0.1), then it won't be possible, since RAD 8.5 uses Eclipse 3.6 while Worklight Studio needs to be installed on 4.2.2

An older version of Worklight Studio would allow you to do that combination, but if you are willing to do a migration, the best would be to get some flavor or RAD 9 (which is based on Eclipse 4.2, then compatible with Worklight Studio).

Regards
Orlando

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helps out a lot. I'm also wondering about steps for installing the worklight plugin itself in RAD. In my version of RAD (8.5), I don't event see the option to download software from the eclipse marketplace. Is there another way to download the plugin? Possibly as a binary package?

Comment: You can try the installation as: Help -> Install New Software, then in the opening dialog put this URL: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/ press enter and continue from there. I got that one from here: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-worklight-developer-edition#.U6RHHu1Du2Y By the way, notice that Worklight 6.2 was released today, so that's the only version you can get from marketplace. You can still get older binaries, but you need to be an IBM Worklight Customer for that.